# What do I have to do as a freelancer to make sure my work is legal?

Tags: taxes, business-plan

I am a freelancer who works in a variety of different fields doing odd jobs for multiple people, usually weekly. Right now I make about $50 a week, however, I have been considering contacting more people so that I can work more. I was wondering what is the best way for me to make sure that all of the work I am doing is legal, and that I am not evading taxes or anything like that.

Here are a few things you should know:

- I am only sixteen years old.
- I plan to make over $1,000 a month. ($12,000 a year.)
- I have a job working at an ad agency doing similar work.

My plan was to get a business license in California, register a domain, run a website, etc. Is there anything I should know? Even if it doesn't apply specifically to my situation I would love to hear it!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to Freelancing.SE! There is a whole slew of things you can, should or need to do. We need you to focus on one aspect, and [edit] to ask that one focused question. If you need more help, see [ask], [meta] or join us in [chat]. I wish you luck, and let us know when you edit the question so we can try to open it again.